# How to get the current animation step from a CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

I'm currently creating a small button with two different states. Every state is represented by two `CAShapeLayer`s and the transition between the states is animated with a series of `CAKeyframeAnimation`s/`CABasicAnimation`s, which all change the path property of the shape layers. My question is how do I animate to a state starting from a current animation (i.e. button is pressed while animating).

Normally, I would ask the presentation layer for the current property value and use an additive animation (as perfectly described [here](http://ronnqvi.st/multiple-animations/)), but since this is a multi-step animation I would have to figure out which step I am currently animating and then chain the appropriate animation to reverse to the previous state. But that is rather tricky (I wanted to have all the animation be `removeOnCompletion=false` and query the time offset of the animations to figure out which animation is currently active and how far).

Unfortunately, setting the layer speed to 0.0 and just animating the `timeOffset` back and forth doesn't work either, since I have secondary animations which behave differently in the opposite direction.

Using a custom layer property for the shape layers seems cumbersome, but I could match a progress property more easily to the current animation step.

Answer (score 2):

So after some trial and error I come up with the following "solution": I use a `CADisplayLink` to get a time update for every frame and by subtracting the current timestamp from the timestamp when the animation started, I can figure out the elapsed animation time, thus the progress (by dividing through animationDuration). That way I can start the reverse animation with an offset. Internally, I calculate the next frame from the keyframe animation and adjust the keyTimes for the new duration. 
You can see an implementation of this [here](https://github.com/fruitcoder/PlayButton/blob/develop/PlayButton/Classes/PlayButton.swift)